# Can I get inlining to apply to source location information?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, compilation, debug-information

I'm writing code in a C-like language, and am using an `inline` function which does actually tend to get inlined. However, the inlining maintains the location in that function's source, in terms of the debugging info added by the compiler (e.g. DWARF added by GCC).

Is it possible to get the compiler to inline the function's code while attributing the instructions to the line at which the function was inlined?

For the sake of discussion, let's assume I'm writing C++ and compiling with GCC on Linux (although a more general answer is appreciated.)

(The motivation has to do with profiling where you only sample the function you're in but don't sample the entire stack.)

Comment: I believe that's generally hardly possible due to optimizations and the as-if rule. Consider the following example: https://godbolt.org/z/Ee9T1r. All the code was reduced to a single instruction (`mov eax, 3`). How would you determine to which part of the code this instruction belongs?

Comment: @DanielLangr: We're talking about changes to debugging information only; it's the same optimizations and the same semantics. In your example, I expect to the code to be associated with line 9. However - that is not a very interesting example. If `add()` in your example issue some system call or something else which does actually get executed, then what I'm asking for is to get line 9 instead of line 3 for that system call.

Comment: I think this is the opposite of what most people try to achieve with debug info, so I doubt you can request it. Maybe you could template the method with a tag of the unnamed namespace, so you get a separate function per compilation unit?

Comment: The debug info contains the information if an instruction is an inline function, and where it was inlined. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @ssbssa: Not exactly. I want the debug information for an instruction to indicate the location it was inlined at, rather than the location in the inlined function's code which resulted in the instruction.

Comment: Yes, as I said, the debug info contains the information where a function was inlined.

Comment: @ssbssa: 1. Perhaps; can you link to an illustration/explanation of this? 2. When some/most profilers show you where you were in the code at various points in time, they won't use that information. They'll just note you were within the inlined function.

Comment: E.g. `addr2line -i` shows inlined function + where it was inlined. And I would expect that at least the modern profilers use this info as well.

Comment: @ssbssa: Can you make your comments into an answer? I might not like it, but I guess it should be one,.

Answer (score 0):

The [`artificial` function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-artificial-function-attribute) does this:

> `artificial`
>
> This attribute is useful for small inline wrappers that if possible should appear during debugging as a unit. Depending on the debug info format it either means marking the function as artificial or using the caller location for all instructions within the inlined body.

Placement of the `__attribute__` directive is a bit tricky. This is the recommended place:

```
inline void __attribute__ ((artificial))
increment (int &i)
{
  ++i;
}
```

This is different from the place in the C++ syntax:

```
[[gnu::artificial]]
inline void
increment (int &i)
{
  ++i;
}
```

The `artificial` attribute is recognized by Clang and compilers derived from it.

Comment: But does this really do what I need it to? See [this GodBolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/Wj7zMv) - it seems the addition is associated with the inner, not the outer, function.

Comment: How did you check this?

Comment: Follow the link. You'll see the color-coding of the `add` instruction is associated with the single line of the inlined `add()` function - not with the line where it was invoked.

Comment: Looks like Godbolt doesn't process `DW_AT_artificial` in this scenario (which is perhaps reasonable). You can work around that using `-gstabs`, but that's not going to work well for C++ debugging in general.

Comment: I don't see such a directive/tag when I compile the source of that program to assembly; or when I remove all of the GodBolt filters. Are you sure it's in there? ... Interestingly, if I compile with `-gstabs` there, everything works fine and the `artificial` is respected.